# Executing java program from bash script does not work

Tags: java, bash, shell, scripting

I am trying to run a java program (weka) from a bash script. The script takes as arguments an inputfile, an outputfile and the content of file containing the command to run the java program (environment variable `$CMD`). The script does not work as I wish and informs me that I use an unknown option for java. I tried to echo the command that the program sends to the shell, and the output is exactly the right command. So I assume that the echo output and the command sent to the shell are not the same.

So please tell me: What did I do wrong?

What is the difference between the output I get...

> echo "java $(cat $CMD) $in > $out"

...and the command the computer gets?

> java "$(cat $CMD)" $in > $out

If more information is needed, please comment!

### Edit:

For those familiar with weka (or familiar with java), this is what I want to get, and what is printed to me by `echo`:

```
java -cp /usr/share/java/weka.jar weka.filters.supervised.attribute.AttributeSelection -E "weka.attributeSelection.ClassifierSubsetEval -B weka.classifiers.bayes.NaiveBayes -T" -S "weka.attributeSelection.BestFirst -D 1 -N 14" -i /home/aldorado/weka_examples/iris.arff > /home/aldorado/weka_examples/irisselected131113.txt
```

Comment: what is printed on `echo`?

Comment: so echo should print "java" following the content of the "command.txt" file which contains the information about the programm (weka) plus options for the programm. Then there is $in which contains the path of the input file for weka, and $out contains the path of the output file.

Answer (score 3):

Add `set -x` in before the line which causes trouble.

That will make the computer print the command again as it understood it. You will see something like

```
 + 'java' '-classpath weka.jar name.of.the.main.Class' 'inputFile' > 'outputFile'
```

Note that quotes which the shell uses to tell you "this was one word / argument for me". It's very useful to notice problems with white space and quoting.

Note that it is very hard to get something like `java "$(cat $CMD)" $in > $out` working. I suggest to move the `java` into `$CMD`. That will allow you to say:

```
bash "./$CMD" $in > $out
```

or, if you make the file executable:

```
"./$CMD" "$in" > $out
```

Use `"$1"` in the file `$CMD` to get a property quoted reference to `"$in"`:

```
cp="weka.jar"
cp="$cp;other.jar"
cp="$cp;more.jar"
cp="$cp;foo.jar"

java -classpath "$cp" name.of.the.main.Class "$1"
```

Comment: Thank you! The problem is that I just started using bash. It is quite likely that I implement things in a clumsy way. I started with a script that my supervisor gave me and modified it for my needs - But as you see it did not work. I will include the java into the command.